# SQL Union Clause Optimization

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

If my query is as follows, how can I optimize it to run more quickly? `things`, `tables` are constant. `different_tables` is another set of tables.

```
Select * from (
    select things from tables where condition 1
    Union
    select things from tables where condition 2
    union
    select things from tables where condition 3
    union
    select things from different_tables where condition 4
    union 
    select things from different_tables where condition 5
)
```

Comment: If `tables` is one table, and `different_tables` are the same table, you can use OR in your conditions.

`select things from tables where condition 1 or condition 2 or condition 3
UNION
select things from different_tables where condition 4 or condition 5`

Comment: Your Oracle version would be relevant here. 12c has a new [concurrent parallel execution](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-1F4C90F9-3EF5-423A-B55B-2593FB3F1433.htm) feature for `union all` queries. Do you need `union`, or could you get by with `union all`?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is view the row source operations (RSO) that are taking longer than others. If you're fortunate, you'll discover low hanging fruit like late filtering. The tools that you use to view the RSOs depend on your license. One thing that comes for free is extended SQL trace. But finding a profiler that makes it easy to understand the RSOs is the key. It might be true that there is a simple fix. But it might be true that you have a very long optimization road ahead. Trace it and know. Don't guess.

Comment: This is an impossible question to answer. It is too vague. Performance tuning is all about the details: data volumes, data skew, available indexes, business rules, etc. Obviously you may have confidentiality reasons for obfuscating your query but unless you can post something specific we can't help you. The internet is full of generals articles about approaching tuning problems. You need to start Googling.

Comment: `Select * from (
    select things from tables where condition 1 AND condition 2 AND condition 3
    union
    select things from different_tables where condition 4 AND condition 5
)` -> That's the most optimized approach, given the information provided.  Further - it depends on the actual tables, the data in them and any other possible way to JOIN the `tables` and `different_tables` tables. Also, depending on the use case, you can either Materialize the query and put it in a flat table, or just insert it in a table, so you can access it more quickly.

Comment: `UNION` queries are quite a rare thing. The reason is that in a good database you have one table per entity, e.g. one for employees, one for departments. This makes it unlikely to retrieve data from one set of tables and data from another set of tables and treat them as one result. Why for instance should I list names, some of them employee names, some of them departent names?

Comment: `UNION` - as opposed to `UNION ALL` - even looks for duplicates in the union result and removes them. This is even less frequently needed. I don't say you never need `UNION` / `UNION ALL`, but it may very well be that your query can (and should) be written without them. It's just a hint; I don't know your queries of course.

Answer (score 3):

**Why so many unions?**

For starters we can significantly cut down on the amount of unions by using an `IN()` statement. This action alone will save you a large amount of overhead. It's actually equivalent to using a series of `or` conditions, but it's much easier to read and write.

```
select * from (
  select things from tables where condition in (1,2,3)
  union
  select things from different_tables where condition in (4,5)
)
```

---

**Is condition indexed?**

If `condition` is not indexed, you should consider indexing it.

---

**Why the derived table?**

In the example you posted, there's no reason to use a derived table, simply using

```
select things from tables where condition in (1,2,3)

union

select things from different_tables where condition in (4,5)
```

should suffice

---

An example with a more complex `where` clause.

```
select 
  things 
from 
  tables 
where 
  condition_1 in (1,2,3)
  or condition_2 = 4
  or (
    condition_1     = 1
    and condition_3 = 5
  )
```

The above example shows a query that will pull records if any of the three major conditions are met. If you're operating on the same table, you should still be able to combine your queries.

Comment: Just an (obvious) note: `in` is used to check a single column's value against a set of values. In the answer, the first query would check if the value of the `condition` column is either 1, 2, or 3. `in` cannot be used to do multiple checks, etc. For example, you can't do `in (condition=1, other_condition>5, last_condition is not null)`. It's not clear how comfortable OP is with SQL, so I want to point this out.

Comment: Still learning, appreciate the help. Each of these conditions have multiple checks and combine other conditions so do you have any suggestions with that?

Comment: @VarunRajagopal: Sure, use an `or` statement.

Comment: @RobbieToyota: I did not think to clarify that. Thank you for the input.

Comment: @VarunRajagopal: If that answered your question, please consider accepting the answer :)